# Array not updating when I add new object to it after spreading array first

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On click of a button I want to update my `channels` array, and add a new channel but it is not working. Here is the function that is executed when the array is updated.

````
  const channelData = setupChannels(venue !== null ? venue.chatRooms : []); 
  const [channelName, setChannelName] = useState('');
  const [categoryName, setCategoryName] = useState('');
  const [channels, setChannels] = useState(channelData);``` 

const onAddChannelClick  = () => {
    if (channelName === '') {
      return;
    }
    let existingChannels = [...channels];
    let newChannel = {
      key: existingChannels.length,
      name: channelName,
      deletable: true,
      markedForDelete: false,
      category: categoryName
    };
    existingChannels.push(newChannel);
    console.log(newChannel);
    setChannels(existingChannels);
    setChannelName('');
    setCategoryName('');
    setCreateChannel(false);
    console.log(existingChannels);
    console.log(channels);
  };
````

In the first console log `console.log(newChannel);` I see my new channel with all the keys and values.  When I `console.log(existingChannels);`I see all the array with my `newChannel` added to it but all the `categories` are `undefined` and when I `console.log(channels)` my whole `newChannel` object is not added and all of the `categories` are `undefined`.

Can anyone see anything wrong with this code or is the issue most likely coming from somewhere else?

Comment: React set states is asynchronous so console logging directly after setting the state will show old values.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear of why `category` is `undefined`. but you can't console `channels` immediately after `setChannels`, as the data wouldn't have updated already.

Use `useEffect` instead to log the data.. or you would find it updated if you are looping them in the `return`.

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(channels)
}, [channels]);
```

Comment: ok thank you I will try that with the `channels` and see if my `newChannel` has actually been added.